# Unity Box Collider 2D IsTrigger still colliding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

I have a **2D Rectangular Tilemap** in Unity which has a **Tilemap Collider 2D** component.
Then I also have a GameObject Player with a **Rigidbody 2D** and two **Box Colliders 2D**.
One of the Box Colliders has the default settings and the second one is bigger and is set to IsTrigger.
The Player is linked with a Prefab of the Player and it has the exact same Components.

So my problem is that the second Collider still collides with the Tilemap Collider.

[image: Player GameObject]

[image: Tilemap Collision]

### Function to pick up the Items

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
   Item item = collider.GetComponent<Item>();
            
   if (item) 
   {
      foreach (ItemWrapper itemWrapper in item.items) 
      {
          inventory.addItem(itemWrapper.item, itemWrapper.amount);
      }

      if (item.getsDestroyed) 
      {
          Destroy(collider.gameObject);
      }
      else 
      {
          item.items = new List<ItemWrapper>();
      }
    }
}
```

### Function to check if I can move

```
void FixedUpdate(){
        float currentMoveSpeed = moveSpeed;

        if(_movementInput != Vector2.zero){
            Vector3 playerPosition = transform.position;
            if (IsOnPathTilemap(playerPosition)) {
                currentMoveSpeed *= boostedSpeedMultiplier;
            }
            
            bool success = TryMove(_movementInput, currentMoveSpeed);
            if(!success) {
                success = TryMove(new Vector2(_movementInput.x, 0), currentMoveSpeed);
            }
            if(!success) {
                success = TryMove(new Vector2(0, _movementInput.y), currentMoveSpeed);
            }

            // Set Animation-Type
            if (success) {

                if (_movementInput.x < 0 || _movementInput.x > 0) { // Horizontal
                    _animator.SetInteger("isMovingDirection", 2);
                    
                } 

                else if (_movementInput.y < 0) { // Down
                    _animator.SetInteger("isMovingDirection", 1);
                } else if (_movementInput.y > 0){ // Up
                    _animator.SetInteger("isMovingDirection", 3);
                } 
                
            } else {
                _animator.SetInteger("isMovingDirection", 0);
            }
            
        } else {
            _animator.SetInteger("isMovingDirection", 0);
        }
        // Set direction of sprite to movement direction
        if(_movementInput.x < 0) {
            _spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
        } else if (_movementInput.x > 0) {
            _spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
        }
    }

private bool TryMove(Vector2 direction, float speed) {
        if(direction != Vector2.zero) {
            // Check for potential collisions
            int count = _rb.Cast(
                direction, // X and Y values between -1 and 1 that represent the direction from the body to look for collisions
                movementFilter, // The settings that determine where a collision can occur on such as layers to collide with
                castCollisions, // List of collisions to store the found collisions into after the Cast is finished
                speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset); // The amount to cast equal to the movement plus an offset

            if(count == 0){
                _rb.MovePosition(_rb.position + direction * (speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Can't move if there's no direction to move in
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I tried to fix this by modifying the Layer Overrides, removing the collision from the Prefab, disabling all the collisions in the Layer Collision Matrix, changing the Layers of the GameObject and Tilemap and some more stuff.

You can probably see that I'm new to Unity, so i dind't really understand that much of what i did.
Of course I googled, trying to understand how the whole thing works but I wasn't successful.

Thanks very much for your time in advance.

Comment: why have two colliders there at all? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the second one is there so i can detect if other GameObjects (Item) are in the area. It should then copy some values from the detected GameObject and destroy it afterwards. I will extend the original post with the OnTriggerEnter2D(); function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to handle both things on the same object I would rather move your collider to its own object

```
Player (non-Trigger)
|-- Item Detector (IsTrigger)
```

an then have your component find and apply values to the player component

```
public class ItemDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private PlayerController payerController;

    private void Awake()
    {
        FetchComponents();
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        FetchComponents();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(!other.TryGetComponent<Item>(out var item)) return;
        
        foreach(var itemWrapper in item.items) 
        {
            // TODO implement this in PlayerController 
            payerController.AddToInventory(itemWrapper.item, itemWrapper.amount);
        }

        // This I would even implement inside the Item class itself
        // There is no need to expose the "getsDestroyed"
        if (item.getsDestroyed) 
        {
            Destroy(item.gameObject);
        }
        else 
        {
            // Instead of deleting and recreating a new list (-> GC waste)
            // rather stick to the existing one and only empty it
            // This could then be private and to the public you only expose an IReadOnlyList
            // so it can't be modified from the outside
            item.items.Clear();
        }
    }

    [ContextMenu(nameof(FetchComponents))]
    private void FetchComponents()
    {
        if(!payerController) payerController = GetComponentInParent<PlayerController>();

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if(!Application.isPlaying)
        {
            UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        }
#endif
    } 
}
```

Now the `Player` and `Item Detector` object can be on different layers and you can configure the layer collision matrix accordingly

Comment: Thank you so much! If I understand correctly, the item detector is in the player. So subordinated in the hierarchy.

Comment: @Liuuner exactly it would simply be a child of it so it moves along just the same as if it was attached to the player directly